# Divide MySQL data into four equal bootstrap row order by alphabet

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I have a table of category, I want to show category data into 4 equal bootstraps 4 rows dynamically, and data must be shown in alphabetically order.

First I am counting the number of data and dividing by 4 then run 4 queries to find the first 25 data and in the second query next 25 data and so on, but looking for a better solution.

```
$catCount = Category::all()->count();

$inOneRow = intval( $catCount / 4);
```

What I want

[image]

Comment: How does the data look in DB? Looks to me like you could do 1 query.. count results then divide by 4... for starters.

Comment: Further, if you KNOW you want 4 columns of 25... why not limit the query to 100 - save memory and processing/cut back logic needed.

Comment: Here I suppose if the table has 100 number of data and when I divide into 4 then I get 25 (but data may be less or more)

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to clarify where that 25 came from. Anyhow, ask yourself which data you need, then make the according query. Formatting that data can be done in a second step. In other words, a single query is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Category is a table of category names - you can select ALL categories at once and use the [ORDER BY clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php) on the query:

```
$query = 'SELECT name FROM db.categories ORDER BY name ASC;';
```

You can alternatively use [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) on the result-set:

```
$query = 'SELECT name FROM db.categories;';
/* execute query here... */
sort($resultSet);
```

Let's assume you did this, the styling would be easy using bootstrap grid (notice mock result-set in fiddles):

```
<?php
const NUM_COLS = 4;
$numResults = count($dummyResult);
$numPerCol = round($numResults / NUM_COLS);
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            for($i = 0, $col = 0; $col < NUM_COLS; $col++){
                echo '<div class="col">';
                for($colLimit = min($numResults, $i + $numPerCol); $i < $colLimit; $i++){
                    echo '<div class="row">'.$dummyResult[$i]['category'].'</div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gw5f-qjyk)

---

Easier to understand, albeit probably slower example:

```
<?php
const NUM_COLS = 4;
$numResults = count($dummyResult);
$numPerCol = round($numResults / NUM_COLS);
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < NUM_COLS; $i++){
                echo '<div class="col">';
                foreach( array_splice($dummyResult, 0, $numPerCol) as $row ){
                    echo '<div class="col">'.$row['category'].'</div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2upq-x7t2)

---

Note: Container will be 100% width of it's parent, unless styled otherwise.
Column widths will be equal by default. See [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).